# Is there a way to access an array of col tags for a table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that looks like:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <col id="name" />
    <col id="birthYear" />
    <col id="phone" />
    <td>
        <tr>Joe</tr>
        <tr>1972</tr>
        <tr>202-555-1234</tr>
    </td>
</table>
```

Is there an easy way to get an array of the `<col />` tags? I don't want to use getElementById because I don't know the ids of the col tags, although I will know the Id of the table. I don't want to use getElementsByTagName because there will be several tables in the document with col tags.

I'm not using jquery, just regular javascript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

getElementsByTagName can be used on table with id "myTable" : it will returns all col of this table.

here is an example :

```
document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("col")
```

Comment: You mean: `colArray=document.getElementById('myTable).getElementsByTagName('col');` ?

Comment: Guess we were typing at the same time. :)

Answer (score 4):

Javascript supports XPath:

```
document.evaluate('//col', document.getElementById('myTable'));
```

Comment: Do all browsers support document.evaluate? I thought IE was still lacking? If IE does support this is definitely the way to go!!!

Comment: I believe IE9 does, and IE8 had buggy support(?), 7 and earlier don't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681968/document-evaluate-cross-browser

Comment: IE older than 9 does not support this http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/DocumentEvaluateMethod