# vanilla javascript prefix begins with css selector

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors, vendor-prefix

Does anyone know a solid way to run a [class^='xyz-'] css selector search in vanilla js, without any libraries, on the whole dom without shutting down the browser?

Basically a $('[class^="xyz-"]').length check without the use of jQuery... it only needs to find one occurrence and can break; right after.

Thank you!

edit: should be cross browser & mobile, possibly ie7+

Comment: I could, but I could also ask on a community driven question and answer website if someone already knows a good way to do this without hacking around for 3 days and possibly ending up with a semi working solution.

Comment: looking for slim libraries, all too big - then the latter as explained above.

Comment: I voting to close this as too broad - if there was a reusable solution simple enough for a stackoverflow answer which worked reliably cross browser do you really think people would be using jQuery and its ilks? If you want a lead than look into [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and the various polyfills for it - like Sizzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy enough with XPath. Faster, too.

```js
var xpathResult = document.evaluate(
  'count(//div[starts-with(@class, "xyz-")])',
  document,
  null,
  XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
snippet.log(xpathResult.numberValue);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
 
<div></div>
<div class="xyz-foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div></div>
```

A slow option (I believe IE6+):

```js
function getElementsByClassNamePrefix(prefix) {
  var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].className.substr(0, prefix.length) == prefix) {
      result.push(els[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
snippet.log(getElementsByClassNamePrefix('xyz-').length);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
 
<div></div>
<div class="xyz-foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: hmm... looks neat... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681968/document-evaluate-cross-browser says no IE support :/
I also need to have it run pretty much on any browser... incl. mobile

Comment: That's true. If so, you're pretty much either limited to Sizzle/jQuery, or traversing DOM yourself and counting things manually (which is what Sizzle would do anyway).

Comment: If HTML is under your control, you could also set a `xyz` class whenever you set a `xyz-foo` class. Then finding all `.xyz` elements is easier, and existing polyfills can target it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this combined with `querySelector`.

```
document.querySelector("[class^='xyz-']");
```

You could also do this with `querySelectorAll` if you need more than one element.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koppamcc/1/) which will log items into the console.

Comment: need it to run on pretty much every browser - are there easy ways for a simple fallback without loading a massive library?

Comment: @Tobias Are you asking if it runs on every browser?

Comment: correct - I'm not sure if this supports older browsers

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this will work on older browsers, basically any browser that supports `querySelector`

Comment: @Tobias I've tested this on several older browsers, it has worked on all of them. It should fit your needs

Comment: I guess I could just put it into a try/catch... it seems to be supported from IE8+

Comment: @Tobias After doing some research, I've found that `querySelectorAll` is the equivalent of using `$` in jQuery, so it has good cross-browser support.